# paginate_by_sql and Rails3.0.0Beta4

Tags: pagination, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to port an existing rails app running rails 2.3.8 to 
3.0.0beta4.

I currently use this paginate_by_sql hack

```
module ActiveRecord 
    class Base 
        def self.find_by_sql_with_limit(sql, offset, limit) 
            sql = sanitize_sql(sql) 
            add_limit!(sql, {:limit => limit, :offset => offset}) 
            find_by_sql(sql) 
        end 
        def self.count_by_sql_wrapping_select_query(sql) 
            sql = sanitize_sql(sql) 
            count_by_sql("select count(*) from (#{sql}) as x") 
        end 
   end 
end
```

The add_limit! method has been removed from ActiveRecord::Base class. 
Are there any work arounds for this?  Any alternatives to doing 
pagination by SQL in Rails 3.0.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, fwiw, this seems to work.

```
module ActiveRecord 
    class Base 
        def self.find_by_sql_with_limit(sql, offset, limit) 
            sql = sanitize_sql(sql) 
            find_by_sql(sql + " LIMIT #{offset},#{limit}") 
        end 
        def self.count_by_sql_wrapping_select_query(sql) 
            sql = sanitize_sql(sql) 
            count_by_sql("select count(*) from (#{sql}) as x") 
        end 
   end 
end
```

You can save it in Application Controller. It has to be loaded first before any ActiveRecord class is loaded, so ApplicationController would be a good place.

Comment: This is what I have done and it works :)

http://thebogles.com/blog/2006/06/paginate_by_sql-for-rails-a-more-general-approach/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just stumbled across a similar issue and hopefully can help someone else.  To fix this, make sure you are using the Rails 3 compatible version of will_paginate by adding

```
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
```

to your Gemfile